# delete detail from database using spring-data-jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Now I am using spring-data-jpa & hibernate. I want to delete a courseDetail from the course, But after I run my code below the courseDetail is still in the database.

Who can tell me how this happened?

thanks in advance.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void deleteCourseDetail(Long id, Long courseId) {
    Course course = courseDao.findOne(courseId);
    CourseDetail courseDetail = courseDetailDao.findOne(id);
    System.out.println(course.getCourseDetails().size());
    course.getCourseDetails().remove(courseDetail);
    System.out.println("after: " + course.getCourseDetails().size());
    courseDao.save(course);
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
public List<CourseDetail> getCourseDetails() {
    return courseDetails;
}
```

Now it works after I add courseDetailDao.delete(id); behind save method. but WHY?

Comment: Go through http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades

Answer (score 1):

You should have "delete orphan" as the cascade type.

If not, deleting an entry in `courseDetails` simply means removing the relationship between `Course` and `CourseDetail`.  It does not mean removing a courseDetail from DB